# Why can't I load this solution in Visual Studio after the VS re-installation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am not so into **.NET** (I came from Java) and I have the following problem. I started a .NET project in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

Then I uninstalled Visual Studio (because I obtained the exception messages in Italian language, so reading here I found that maybe uninstalling VS and installing it again with only the English language avoiding the Italian one it can solve the problem).

Ok, I reinstalled it selecting only the English language pack.

The problem is that now I can't open again my project in fact doing:

```
File --> Open --> Project/Solution
```

then I select the folder of my project then I select the `.sln` file of this project.

The problem is that the project is not loaded and into the Solution Explorer; I get the following error message:

> Unavailable, the project file was unloaded

Here is what I see:

[image]

Why is this? What could be the problem? How can I try to fix and correctly load my solution?

Comment: You can get something like that if you haven't installed support for that project type, e.g. C++ or Azure tools or web. But I didn't think it was exactly that, and I thought it gave you more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unavailable" like that usually means it literally cannot find the project file.

Make sure the csproj is on disk, and at the locations specified in the .sln file.

Comment: I didn't installed the web development platform

Answer (score 1):

Try running VS19 as an admin. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A project may be unloaded from Visual Studio to allow you to edit the project file, or to allow something else to modify it (as I suspect is the case here). You can do this by right-clicking on the project and selecting 'Unload Project'

To re-load the project, right-click on it and select 'Reload Project'.
Of course, if the project file is missing or damaged (as mentioned in the other answer) this may not work. If this is the case, try and find the .csproj file or edit it manually to see if you can fix what's broken.

Answer (score 0):

Running as an Admin worked for me. I get this issue everytime I update my Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but I faced this and i had to load all projects(option from context menu on solution)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the project only from the folder. This is: `(Menu) File → Open → Folder`. And not directly from the solution, which is: `(Menu) File → Open → Project/Solution`.